# Error: Unexpected module instantiations outside module boundaries

Tags: verilog, hdl

I am trying to create a 32-bit counter that breaks the 32 inputs into 4 groups of 8 then feeds those 4 groups into a mux.
This is what I have:

```
modules Bit32 ( clk, reset, load, D, Q);
input clk, reset, load, D, Q;
input [7:0] D;
input [15:8] D;
input [23:16] D;
input [31:24] D;
output [7:0] Q;
output [15:8] Q;
output [23:16] Q;
output [31:24] Q;
reg [7:0] Q;
reg [15:8] Q;
reg [23:16] Q;
reg [31:24] Q;
always @(posedge clk)
    if(reset) Q <=32'b0; else 
    if (load) Q <=D;
    else Q <=Q + 32'b1
endmodule
```

I receive these errors:

> ERROR:HDLCompiler:944 -
>   "C:/Users/Skyla/Documents/csulb/Fall17/201/assign5/Bit32.v" Line 1:
>   Unexpected module instantiations outside module boundaries.
>
> WARNING:HDLCompiler:1591 -
>   "C:/Users/Skyla/Documents/csulb/Fall17/201/assign5/Bit32.v" Line 1:
>   Root scope declaration is not allowed in verilog 95/2K mode
>
> ERROR:HDLCompiler:806 -
>   "C:/Users/Skyla/Documents/csulb/Fall17/201/assign5/Bit32.v" Line 2:
>   Syntax error near "input".

My mux:

```
module CounterMux(select, D, Q);
input[1:0] select;
input[3:0] D:
output Q;

wire Q;
wire [1:0] select;
wire [3:0] D;

assign Q=D[select];

endmodule
```

Comment: In `Bit32` you declared `D` and `Q` 5 times ( 1 as single bit, 4 as 8-bits). In `CounterMux` there is an obvious typo. I suggest you learn and implent an ANSI header style. It is fewer lines of code, easier to read, and less error prone. The Non-ANSI style if for backward comparability support.

Comment: @Greg Im using verilog hdl, im not sure what is ANSI? I'm just a beginner

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bverilog%5D+ANSI most answers have direct quotes and links form IEEE1364 (Verilog) and the IEEE1800 (SystemVerilog)

Answer (score 0):

The errors and warnings for the `Bit32.v` file are due to a typo: the keyword is `module`, not `modules` (notice the "s").  Change:

```
modules Bit32 ( clk, reset, load, D, Q);
```

to:

```
module Bit32 ( clk, reset, load, D, Q);
```

The compiler thought you were placing an instance of a module named `modules` .  Making that change gets rid of the messages you showed.

---

But there are other errors in the `Bit32.v` file.  You should not declare multiple ports with the same name.  You declared `D` and `Q` 5 times each, but they must only be declared once each.  For example:

```
module Bit32 ( clk, reset, load, D, Q);
input clk, reset, load;
input [31:0] D;
output [31:0] Q;
reg [31:0] Q;
always @(posedge clk)
    if (reset) Q <= 32'b0;
    else if (load) Q <= D;
    else Q <= Q + 32'b1;
endmodule
```

---

I also got a compile error because there was a missing semicolon after `else Q <=Q + 32'b1`.  I believe the IEEE Std requires a semicolon after each statement.  Although some compilers apparently don't require it, it is best to have it for portability.